# Python pip how to handle third party dependencies

Tags: python, pip

I am working on a python module which gets installed inside a `virtual-env`. The module depends on third party python modules such as pandas, matplotlib etc which them self depend on non-python packages to compile.

My setup.py looks something like this

```
config = {
          'packages': ['name'],
          'install_requires': ['numpy',
                               'pandas',
                               'cython',
                               'matplotlib',
                              ],
          'name': 'name',
         }
setup(**config)
```

My current work flow is to `pip install` the package and wait for compilation errors and install missing dependencies manually. However if i give the module to my colleagues this might become a pain in the butt.

Is there a way to tell pip to install non-python dependencies like

```
'external_requires': ['gcc',
                     ],

'external_install':  ['apt-get install']
```

or to call an install script ? What is best practise ?

Answer (score 2):

Best practice depends on the target audience, but since

- `apt-get` is specific to Debian/Ubuntu and derivatives
- It requires superuser privileges
- Packages names tend to change between releases

and
finally

- Packages may conflict, I tend to put this stuff in a README instead of a script.

Comment: the problem with README files is, that they are ignored because my colleagues rather bother me ;)

Comment: @greole Then maybe it's time to teach them to RTFM before they come to your door.